# Is accessing the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Keys property thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

For example can I go:

```
string[] keys = new string[items.Count];
items.Keys.CopyTo(keys);
```

Where items is a:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject>
```

instance that could be being modified by another thread? (Its not clear to me if when accessing the Keys property the inner workings of Dictionary iterates the collection - in which case I know it would not be thread safe).

**Update:** I realise my above example is not thread safe becuase the size of the Dictonary could change between the lines. however what about:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> keys = items.Keys;
string[] copyOfKeys = new string[keys.Count];
keys.Keys.CopyTo(copyOfKeys );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Dictionary` is not thread-safe. If you need thread safety and you're using .NET 4 or higher, you should use a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

From MSDN:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently,
>   as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In
>   the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the
>   collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the
>   collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing,
>   you must implement your own synchronization.

Comment: I know Dictionary<T1, T2> is not thread safe - does that mean accessing the Keys Property is not thread safe? (I thought that only meant iterating and modifying is not thread safe).

Comment: Per MSDN, the collection returned by the Keys property is a reference to the Dictionary's keys, so it may abruptly change when the collection is modified.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictionary is being mutated on another thread it is not safe to do this. The first thing that comes to mind is that the dictionary might resize its internal buffer which surely does not play well with concurrent iteration.

If you aren't changing the keys and are only writing values this should be safe in practice.

Anyway, I wouldn't put such code into production because the risk is too high. What if some .NET patch changes the internals of `Dictionary` and suddenly you have a bug. There are other concerns as well.

I recommend you use `ConcurrentDictionary` or some other safe strategy. Why gamble with the correctness of your code?