# Is Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Item[TKey] Property thread safe to set, if key is already in the dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, thread-safety

Before anything, I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062790/is-accessing-the-dictionarytkey-tvalue-keys-property-thread-safe) and I don't think it answers my question.

I'm writing a method to update the values of a dictionary.
**I will not insert nor remove any keys**.

I plan to do this:

```
private static void Example(Dictionary<Individual, float> dict) {
            var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();

            Parallel.For(0, keys.Length, i => {
                var key = keys[i];
                var newValue = DoHardMath(key);
                dict[key] = newValue;
            });         
        }
```

Is this thread-safe?
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item?view=netcore-2.1) doesn't make this clear.

Comment: No, you should use a concurrent dictionary for that. The answer to the question you linked quotes [the documentation for the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-2.1), *"A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified."*, and you will be modifying the collection, so...

Comment: It'a not clear what 'modifying the collection' means, that why I asked.

Comment: No. A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is not thread-safe.

Comment: In your situation, it's safe in that you can replace the value without affecting other key/value pairs in the dictionary. If multiple threads use the same key, then it isn't safe. If you add or remove keys, it isn't safe. Remember that `dict[key] = newValue;` will add a new entry if `key` doesn't already exist. All that being said, it's generally safer to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` - that way you don't have any nasty surprises when you edit the code later on and forget that you shouldn't add/remove items.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very specific, but `ConcurrentDictionary` would avoid the anxiety.

Docos at:

- [ConcurrentDictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-remove-items)